# ElasticSearch: check if nested object array is empty

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I go about fetching all documents w/o any objects in a field?

I have the following mapping:

```
"properties" : {
  "name": {
    "type": "text"
  },
  "nestedArray": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "prop1": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "prop2": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to get all documents where "nestedArray" is empty or doesn't exist.

I'm using elasticSearch 5.0

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-exists-query.html) would solve this problem. Try following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "nestedArray",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "nestedArray"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying the exists query, but I had the nested and bool switched.

Comment: glad I could help

Comment: Thank you! I spent almost an hour looking for this answer.

Comment: thank you. To me it is pretty confusing to use the nested attribute here as I just want to check whether the array is empty and not if one the inside objects value.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
{
  "size": 5000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "nestedArray",
            "query": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "nestedArray"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0
}
```