# Elasticsearch query for the case where the primary field does not exist, not nested one

Tags: elasticsearch, query-optimization

I have a problem with es query for the case where the primary field does not exist, not nested one.
I have these data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "offers": [
            {
                "id": "777",
                "offers": null,
                "name": "Apple"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "offers": null
    }
]
```

and I need to get an item where the primary field `offers` does not exist or equals null (those with `id=2`), not nested one (`id=1`).

I was expecting that the following filter will work:

```
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "offers"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But this filter gives me the item with `id = 1` where the nested `offers` is null.
How to get the item where specifically the primary field does not exist (`id=2`), not the nested one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offers` is a nested type of field. This is an important thing that I was not aware of. I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748400/4003272).
So in my case here is the query that works and which gives item where specifically the primary field does not exist (id=2), not the nested one (id=1):

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "offers",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "filter": {
                                    "exists": {
                                        "field": "offers"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must_not":{
        "bool":{
          "must":[
            {
              "exists":{
                "field":"offers.id"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @joe for the contribution. Unfortunately, It did not work for me because `offers` is a nested field. I found an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748400/4003272

Comment: Oh ok. I assumed your field was trivially "nested", not having an actual `nested` mapping. Glad you found your answer!